# summing up values of columns from multiple files

Tags: python

I have a small problem here, I'm trying to sum up entries from multiple files (50), and each of them contain 3 columns. 
for example, using the first 3 files: file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt which look like:

file1.txt:

```
2 3 4
1 5 6
5 4 7
```

file2.txt:

```
1 2 1
2 3 2
4 3 1
```

file3.txt:

```
6 1 1
1 3 0
3 4 5
```

So my question is how do i sum up all the entries from column one, column two and column three from the 50 files to end up with a file that looks like:

output.txt:

```
9 6 6
4 11 8
12 11 13
```

I've read in the 50 files and appended them but I'm having trouble actually summing the entries one by one.

so I've done this:

```
for p in range(50):
    locals()['first_col%d' % p] = []
    locals()['second_col%d' % p] = []
    locals()['third_col%d' % i] = []

for i in range(1,50):
    f = open("file"+str(i)+".txt","r")
    for line in f:
        locals()['fist_col%d' % i].append(float(line.split()[0]))
        locals()['second_col%d' % i].append(float(line.split()[1]))
        locals()['third_col%d' % i].append(float(line.split()[2]))

f.close()
```

I'm trying to think of a way to put this in a loop that will read in all the first_cols(first_col1,first_col2,first_col3, etc),second_cols and third_cols and sum up the entries.

Comment: Don't try to construct variable names at runtime; use a dictionary. That is, `first_col[p] = []` instead of `locals()['first_col%d'%p]=[]`. Besides, the return value of `locals()` should be treated as read-only; changes are not guaranteed to be visible.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
b_list = []
for l in range(1,4):
    file=open('/Users/sgeorge/file%i.txt' % l, 'r')
    m1=[(i.strip()) for i in file]
    for j in m1:
        b_list.append(filter(None,[(k.strip()) for k in j]))
#print b_list
a = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
for i in range(0,9,3):
    a[0][0] += int(b_list[i][0])
    a[0][1] += int(b_list[i][1])
    a[0][2] += int(b_list[i][2])
for i in range(1,9,3):
    a[1][0] += int(b_list[i][0])
    a[1][1] += int(b_list[i][1])
    a[1][2] += int(b_list[i][2])

for i in range(2,9,3):
    a[2][0] += int(b_list[i][0])
    a[2][1] += int(b_list[i][1])
    a[2][2] += int(b_list[i][2])

for j in a:
    print j[0],j[1],j[2]
```

**Output:**

```
$ python stack.py 
9 6 6
4 11 8
12 11 13
```

The above script is meant to handle only three files (`file1.txt`,`file2.txt` and `file3.txt`)

If you want to handle 50 such files, use following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
b_list = []
for l in range(1,51):
    file=open('/Users/sgeorge/file%i.txt' % l, 'r')
    m1=[(i.strip()) for i in file]
    for j in m1:
        b_list.append(filter(None,[(k.strip()) for k in j]))
#print b_list
a = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
for i in range(0,150,3):
    a[0][0] += int(b_list[i][0])
    a[0][1] += int(b_list[i][1])
    a[0][2] += int(b_list[i][2])
for i in range(1,150,3):
    a[1][0] += int(b_list[i][0])
    a[1][1] += int(b_list[i][1])
    a[1][2] += int(b_list[i][2])

for i in range(2,150,3):
    a[2][0] += int(b_list[i][0])
    a[2][1] += int(b_list[i][1])
    a[2][2] += int(b_list[i][2])

for j in a:
    print j[0],j[1],j[2]
```

**Update:**

```
>>> a=1
>>> b=1.1
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(b)
<type 'float'>
>>> float(a)+float(b)
2.1
>>>
```

**My above script will not handle `float`ing numbers. For handling the same, use the following:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
b_list = []
for l in range(1,4):
    file=open('/Users/sgeorge/file%i.txt' % l, 'r')
    m1=[(i.strip()) for i in file]
    for j in m1:
        b_list.append(j.replace('\n','').split(' '))
#print b_list
a = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
for i in range(0,9,3):
    a[0][0] += float(b_list[i][0])
    a[0][1] += float(b_list[i][1])
    a[0][2] += float(b_list[i][2])
for i in range(1,9,3):
    a[1][0] += float(b_list[i][0])
    a[1][1] += float(b_list[i][1])
    a[1][2] += float(b_list[i][2])
for i in range(2,9,3):
    a[2][0] += float(b_list[i][0])
    a[2][1] += float(b_list[i][1])
    a[2][2] += float(b_list[i][2])
for j in a:
    print j[0],j[1],j[2]
```

**Output:**

```
$ python stack.py 
9.0 6.0 6.0
4.0 11.0 8.0
12.0 11.0 13.0
```

Comment: thank you SUKU. But what if the entries are not intergers, but floating point numbers?

Comment: sorry the error is: 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: .

Comment: You're great SUKU, thank you so much!
I'm actually trying to apply this to a bigger problem: 100 fies (file1.txt...file100.txt), each with 2500 rows and two columns each. Will this work if I remove the lines in each of the for loops  (i.e a[0][2] += float(b_list[i][2]), a[1][2] += float(b_list[i][2]), a[2][2] += float(b_list[i][2]))?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html
load into numpy array and then sum arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from StringIO import StringIO

In [3]: txt ="""2 3 4
   ...: 1 5 6
   ...: 5 4 7"""

In [4]: f = StringIO(txt)

In [5]: arr = np.loadtxt(f,dtype = int)

In [6]: np.sum(arr,axis = 0)
Out[6]: array([ 8, 12, 17])
```