# Sums of entries, Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [summing up values of columns from multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712268/summing-up-values-of-columns-from-multiple-files)

I have a small problem here, I'm trying to sum up entries from multiple files (50), and each of them contain 3 columns. for example, using the first 3 files: file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt which look like:

file1.txt:

```
2 3 4
1 5 6
5 4 7
```

file2.txt:

```
1 2 1
2 3 2
4 3 1
```

file3.txt:

```
6 1 1
1 3 0
3 4 5
```

So my question is how do i sum up all the entries from column one, column two and column three from the 50 files to end up with a file that looks like:

output.txt:

```
9 6 6
4 11 8
12 11 13
```

I've read in the 50 files and appended them but I'm having trouble actually summing the entries one by one.

so I've done this:

```
for p in range(50):
    locals()['first_col%d' % p] = []
    locals()['second_col%d' % p] = []
    locals()['third_col%d' % i] = []

for i in range(1,50):
    f = open("file"+str(i)+".txt","r")
    for line in f:
        locals()['fist_col%d' % i].append(float(line.split()[0]))
        locals()['second_col%d' % i].append(float(line.split()[1]))
        locals()['third_col%d' % i].append(float(line.split()[2]))

f.close()
```

I'm trying to think of a way to put this in a loop that will read in all the `first_cols` (`first_col1` ,`first_col2`, `first_col3`, etc), `second_cols` and `third_cols` and sum up the entries.

Comment: Why ask the exact same question twice? - work instead on making the first question more attractive to answerers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `glob` to wildcard match the filename pattern, then a bit of judicious use of `zip` and abuse `literal_eval` (might want to consider just a generator to convert to `int` instead though) - NB - this expects the same number of columns and rows for each file, otherwise truncation will occur:

```
from glob import glob
from ast import literal_eval

filenames = glob('/home/jon/file*.txt')
files = [open(filename) for filename in filenames]
for rows in zip(*files):
    nums = [literal_eval(row.replace(' ', ',')) for row in rows]
    print map(sum, zip(*nums))

[9, 6, 6]
[4, 11, 8]
[12, 11, 13]
```

Comment: I second the `literal_eval` abuse -- I think that `tuple(int(x) for x in row.split(','))` is a lot better here (less sensitive to extra whitespaces for example).

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that sums file per file, after initializing a container with null values:

```
>>> import os
>>> def sum_files(path):
    result = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
    for fil in os.listdir(path):
        full_path = os.path.join(path, fil)
        for line_nb, line in enumerate(open(full_path)):
            numbers = line.split()
            for col_nb, nb in enumerate(numbers):
                result[line_nb][col_nb] += int(nb)
    return result

>>> sum_files(path)
[[9, 6, 6], [4, 11, 8], [12, 11, 13]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code snippet

```
try:
    output_matrix=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
    for i in range (1,51):
        try:        
            f = open("file"+str(i)+".txt","r")
        except IOError, e:
            continue
        if not f:
            continue
        counter=0
        for line in f:
            row=line.split()
            for row_item in range(0,len(row)):
                output_matrix[counter][row_item]=output_matrix[counter][row_item]+int(row[row_item])
            counter=counter+1
    f = open("Output.txt","w")
    for i in range (0,len(output_matrix)):
        for j in range (0,len(output_matrix[i])):
            f.write(str(output_matrix[i][j]) + ' ')
        f.write('\n')
    f.close()
except Exception,e:
    print str(e)
```